# Follow the minimum value in a collection of values which can only increase

Tags: java, algorithm, collections, min

I have a large collection of integers, the value of which can only grow (I'm counting stuff).

For efficiency reasons, I separately keep a max value, which is updated whenever needed:

```
// when increasing the i'th count
coll[i] += 1;
// check whether also to update the max:
if(coll[i] > max){
  max = coll[i];
}
```

What's an efficient algorithm to also "follow" the *minimum* value of the collection?

By efficient I mean, iterate over the whole collection the least often possible and keep memory footprint small. (the latter is really less important than the former)

I'm using Java: so if said algorithm is already in the JRE, I'd welcome a reference.

Comment: If your collection only grows - the same way you memorize `max` you can memorize `min` - or am I misunderstanding your question?

Comment: Just check if the last element is the largest and if the first element is smallest? Or did I understand something wrong?

Comment: You don't know which elements are minimal, so when one of these minimals gets increased, you don't know if there are others (don't touch the min) or not (increase the min)

Comment: The collection buckets get incremented more or less randomly. Imagine data put in histogram bins.

Comment: @Philipp Each element can increase at anytime? Got it now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Keep a hash table of counts for each value, then update it and also the min if there are no more values equal to `min` in your hash table.

```
// when increasing the i'th count
coll[i] += 1;
--hashTable[coll[i] - 1];
++hashTable[coll[i]];
// check whether also to update the max:
if(coll[i] > max){
  max = coll[i];
}
// check whether to update the min:
if(min == coll[i] - 1 && hashTable[coll[i] - 1] == 0){
  min = coll[i];
}
```

The hash table can be a simple array if you can afford the memory (if your values are small enough) or an actual [Hashtable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Hashtable.html).

This would only require an initial iteration over your collection to build the hash table. Then no more iterations will be performed.

Comment: Thanks, nice and clear! I'll probably use a HashTable as my values are not strictly bounded. So I cannot preassign the array "large enough" to hold all possible values.

Comment: of course, when the minimum is only needed after all counting has been done, just iterating once afterwards is still the better option.